# why is 10 * (7/10) = 7 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

7 and 10 in the expression (7/10) are integers, so the result 0.7 should be integer as well, which is 0, and the result for the entire expression should be 0 too. However, it's giving me the result of 7, why? Is it ignoring the parentheses or converts to double automatically?

Comment: Results don't depend on the format of the inputs, `10/4` is `2.5` - making that `3` would be wrong, but also annoying because it would mean having to write all numbers as their possible decimal accuracy when part of a sum, i.e. `10.0/4.0` and wouldn't be workable for `10/3` --- that result is completely expected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have an integer type, or a double, or a float... it just has 1 type for all numbers: the helpfuly called `Number` type (try `var foo = new Number(7);`, or `var foo = Number('123string');`
Now, I know I said that JS doesn't know of floats, but that's not entirely true. All `Number` type vars/values are, essentially 64 bit floats, as defined by the IEEE 754 standard (which are, indeed, as Jan Dvorak kindly pointed out to me, `double`'s in most staticly typed languages), with all the caveats that brings with it:

```
(.1 + .2);//0.30000000000000004
```

But that's not the point. The point is that, in JS you can perform float + int arithmatic without there ever being a need for internal casts, or conversions. That's why `10*(7/10)` will *always* be 7

Answer (score 11):

JavaScript doesn't distinguish between integers and floating point numbers, everything I believe is considered a double so that is just why you get the result.

Take a look at the details on the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) property on MDN.

Comment: "I'm not a fan of W3Schools really but take a look at their details on the Number property." -- why? Isn't the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) good enough or even better?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I don't regularly develop in JavaScript so wasn't aware of 'MDN'. Thanks though I'll bookmark it.

Comment: @Ian: the type JS uses is `Number`, which (in strong-typed languages) would be a 64bit IEEE 754 float

Comment: W3schools says "you can use the toString() method to output numbers as base 16 (hex), base 8 (octal), or base 2 (binary)". MDN says "parameters: radix - An integer between 2 and 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values". Guess which one is correct?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem sure, but `Number` in Javascript corresponds to what's called `double` in most other strongly typed languages.

Comment: "Note: Infinity is a number (typeof(Infinity) returns a number). " -- go home w3schools, you're drunk :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Dear me... I've been writing too much C today. I'm banging on about 64b precision, forgetting that that, indeed makes it double :) that explains a bug I was trying to fix :D thanks

Comment: @Ian already noticed and reflected by voting appropriately :-)

Answer (score 7):

**There is no int and double in JavaScript**

In JavaScript, both int, flot, and double are normalized to work together. They are treated as 1 (They're treated as as `Number`, which is an **IEEE 754** float. Thanks @Elias Van Ootegem). Equality, Liberty and Fraternity. and thus;

10*0.7 = 7

**JavaScript is not like C**.

Comment: They're not treated as double, they're treated as `Number`, which is an IEEE 754 float

Answer (score 5):

Javascript doesn't have integers, and even if it did, there's nothing that says that `/` needs to return an integer (just because another language may do that doesn't mean every language has to). The operation results in a `float`/`Number`, just like all Javascript numbers are, period.

Comment: Additional thanks for bringing up a point that '/' doesn't have to return an integer

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses dynamic types. That means that a variable like this:

```
var str = "hi";
```

Can later become:

```
str = 123; //now we have an 'int'
str += 0.35; //now str is 123.35, a 'float'
```

So JavaScript doesn't cast floats to ints for example.

If you want to force a "cast" then you have to do:

```
var integer = parseInt( 3.14*9.0291+23, 10 ); //the second parameter (10) is the 'base'
```

But remember, Javascript will not take care of types, that's your problem.

Comment: Always specify the base, when calling `parseInt`, and JS does a pretty good job (9/10) when it comes to taking care of types (`var someVar = 1, aString = 'The result of the sum is: ' + (someVar + 123/3) + ' not ' + 1`. The var `aString` will hold: the result of the sum is 42 not 1

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem if you pass `parseInt` a number, the number will be stringified in such a way `parseInt` cannot make the wrong guess here ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I know, but it's a good habit to get in to, before you know it you'll be using `parseInt` on user input, in which case, the result might be _not_ what you'd expect...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
10*parseInt(7/10)
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you try to follow the rules, then

```
10 * (7/10) --> 10 * .7 --> 7
```

You cannot change the way its gonna result into.

> so the result 0.7 should be integer as well, which is 0

If you want this, then try using

```
Math.Floor();
```

This would change the decimals to the nearest int! Or try out `parse()`